# Distintos resultados de un mismo loop

Tags: bucles, while

Estoy aprendiendo Python en Udemy y me surgió un problema con un loop while.

Mi duda es: ¿Por qué la identación del print cambia el resultado?

1) Caso 1. `if` correcto

```
import random


playerhp = 300
enemyatkl = 60
enemyatkh = 80


while playerhp > 0:
    dmg = random.randrange(enemyatkl, enemyatkh)
    playerhp = playerhp - dmg


    if playerhp <= 10:
        playerhp = 10

    #print de la duda
    print("Enemy strikes for: ", dmg, ". And your heath is: ", playerhp)


    if playerhp == 10:
        print("You have low health. You've been teleported")

        break
```

Da como resultado:

Enemy strikes for:  68 . And your heath is:  232

Enemy strikes for:  66 . And your heath is:  166

Enemy strikes for:  78 . And your heath is:  88

Enemy strikes for:  67 . And your heath is:  30

You have low health. You've been teleported

2) Caso 2. Cambia el print del primer `if`. Resultado no comprendido.

```
import random


playerhp = 300
enemyatkl = 60
enemyatkh = 80


while playerhp > 0:
    dmg = random.randrange(enemyatkl, enemyatkh)
    playerhp = playerhp - dmg


    if playerhp <= 10:
        playerhp = 10

        #print de la duda
        print("Enemy strikes for: ", dmg, ". And your heath is: ", playerhp)


    if playerhp == 10:
        print("You have low health. You've been teleported")

        break
```

Da como resultado:

Enemy strikes for:  71 . And your heath is:  10

You have low health. You've been teleported

Los resultado son distintos. En el primer caso completa todo el loop hasta encontrar el valor de 10. En el segundo caso, el loop termina en la primera iteración, sin completar todo el ciclo.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

P.D: mi primera vez en stack overflow. Una disculpa si lo empleé de una manera incorrecta.

Comment: Bienvenido!! tu pregunta esta bien formularda como esta. Por fa, como referencia mirate [ask]. La identacion es todo en python (pero todo, o sea de eso depende si algo esta dentro o afuera de otra instruccion, como un for, un while o un if).. Seguro un experto te va a poner una respuesta mucho mas completa al respecto, esto es solo un comentario.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En Python, la identación es importante, ya que determinan el comienzo y fin de determinadas instrucciones, a diferencia de otros lenguajes...

En el caso2

Al parecer el while si hace su trabajo completo ya que el playerhp va disminuyendo...

El print lo esta tomando como si estuviera dentro del (if playerhp <= 10:), por eso el resultado solo lo muestra cuando playerhp es menor o igual a 10.

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos!